# C# HttpWebRequest TLS1.3 Operation Timed Out

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, tls1.3

I have a small application that downloads images from the website of one of our suppliers. I know the supplier uses TLS1.3 on his server, so since the application will be running on a Windows server we installed Server 2022 and enabled the TLS1.3.

When I run the application on my Windows 10 PC it downloads the image with no problem, but when I run the same application on our Server it gets timed out every time. Below if the code I am running

```
string ImageUrl = "https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Doc_Ref=PB104452&p_File_Type=rendition_4000_png";
try
{              
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ImageUrl);
    myRequest.Timeout = 15000;
    HttpWebResponse myReponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
    if (myReponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK &&
        myReponse.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
    {
        this.Text = "OK";
    }
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    this.Text = wex.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

I have a small application that downloads images from the website of one of our suppliers. I know the supplier uses TLS1.3 on his server, so since the application will be running on a Windows server we installed Server 2022 and enabled the TLS1.3.

When I run the application on my Windows 10 PC it downloads the image with no problem, but when I run the same application on our Server it gets timed out every time.

Comment: Which version of the .net / .net framework is this compiled with?

Comment: According to [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls): _To ensure .NET Framework applications remain secure, the TLS version should not be hardcoded. .NET Framework applications should use the TLS version the operating system (OS) supports...For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later...When your app lets the OS choose the TLS version: It automatically takes advantage of new protocols added in the future_.

Comment: Timeout is nothing to do with TLS errors. Your machine cannot contact the server of the URL. Also why use `HttpWebRequest` it's basically deprecated, you should use `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: The project targets .NET 4.8.1 and I changed my code to HTTPClient as shown but I still get errors => string sImageUrl = "https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Doc_Ref=PB104452&p_File_Type=rendition_4000_png";
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {                    
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    var response = client.GetAsync(sImageUrl).Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}